# Complex power series: radius of convergence and derivative

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and define the power series by: 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Notice that the sum starts at $n=0$ so the first term is $z^2$

a) show that the series has a radius of convergence $R = \infty$.

Now let $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!} \ , \ x\in\mathbb{R}$$

b) Find the power series of the functions $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and show that 
$f''(x)+f(x) = 2\cos(x) \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

---

a) I know that I can find the radius of convergence by using $R = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|} $. However, when the series on the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$ do I have to perform a index shift of $z^{2n+2}$ or is there another way to calculate the radius of convergence?

b) $$\begin{align}f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cdot(2n+2)x^{2n+1}\\=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}f''(x) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cdot(2n+2)\cdot (2n+1)x^{2n}\\&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(-1)^n(2n+2)(2n+1)x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\right) \end{align}$$

How am I suppose to conclude that $f''(x) + f(x) = 2\cos(x)$?

Comment: Perhaps it may help to note that the numerator can also be written as $z^2(-z^2)^n$

Comment: I am not entirely sure how it helps to rewrite the numerator when it is on the form $z^{2n+2}$ wouldn't it be possible to do a index shift of so that we get it on the form $w^n$, which makes it possible to equation given for R above?

Comment: Tbh I was rushed so just wrote out what I spotted regardless of whether it was any use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the power series

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nw^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$$
Then, $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=0,$ and hence the about power series, for all $w$, and so does is we replace $w$ by $z^2$.

Comment: I understand the index shift, but I am unsure about how you got your limit, since I get: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n\cdot (2n+2)!}{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot (2n+1)!} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left| -2n-2 \right| = \infty$

Comment: @Simbörg What you get is correct, and it is the same with what I got!

Comment: And because the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ for $w$ we have that $R_w = \infty$ which implies that  $\sqrt(R_w)=R_z = \infty$?

Comment: In a sense what you  say is correct. My argument is the following: If the series converges for some $x_0\ne 0$, then its radius of convergence $R$ satisfies $R\ge |x_0|$. Hence, is the p.s. converges for all $x_0$, then $R=\infty$.